# Screenshot with display:none in Extent Reports

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I'm using this extent report:

```
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

And this is my after method:

```
@AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod(ITestResult result) {
        String methodName = result.getMethod().getMethodName();
        if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
            String exceptionMessage = Arrays.toString((result.getThrowable().getStackTrace()));
            extentTest.fail("<details><summary><b><font color=red>Exception Occured, click to see details:"
                    + "</font></b></summary>" + exceptionMessage.replaceAll(",", "<br>") + "</details> \n");

            String path = takeScreenshot(result.getMethod().getMethodName());
            try {
                extentTest.fail(result.getThrowable().getMessage() +
                                "<br><font color=red>" + "Screenshot of failure" + "</font><br>",
                        MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(path).build());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                extentTest.fail("Test Failed, cannot attach screenshot");
            }
```

And this to take screenshot:

```
 private String takeScreenshot(String methodName) {
            String fileName = getScreenshotName(methodName);
            String directory = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/resources/screenshots/";
            new File(directory).mkdirs();
            String path = directory + fileName;
            try {
                File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File(path));
                System.out.println("**********************************");
                System.out.println("Screenshot stored at: " + path);
                System.out.println("**********************************");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return path;
        }
```

However, the screenshot is not been displayed on the report:
[image]

How can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to attach screenshot into extent report html because you forget to call flush() method AT END of @AfterMethod. flush() appends the report HTML file with all the tests result/screenshots. There must be at least one ended test for anything to be appended to the report.

Note: If flush() is called before any of the ended tests, no information will be appended to report.

So correct your code as follows -

```
    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod(ITestResult result) {
       //Your existing code
      try {
          //Your existing code
          } catch (IOException e) {
          //Your existing code
           }
            extent.flush();
      }
```